# CSS inline area cross browser

Tags: html, css, inline

I would like to add some CSS fixed size blocks inline into a text paragraph and I'm having cross browser issues. I use div and inline-block and it works on Firefox. Under IE it fails ([inline-blocks aren't fully supported](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html)).

Is there a simple cross browser solution available?

(The rationale for this is for the fixed size blocks to use background-image for the displaying of smileys. This allows sprites and smileys shown according to the stylesheet.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What element are you applying inline-block on?

> IE 6/7 accepts the value only on
>   elements with a natural display:
>   inline.

So if you're using a `div` right now, switch to a `span`instead.

Comment: @The Feast: Even more, you seem to suggest you're using divs inside a paragraph tag. That's illegal HTML (a `p` can't contain block-level elements), so you should be using a span there anyway.

Comment: Don't forget to use `-moz-inline-box` for older versions of Firefox.

Comment: Thanks - that's done the trick. I'm sure I tried this amongst many things with no success - but some other factor prevented it. @mercator, thanks, I wasn't using a div inside an HTML `p` paragraph, it was compliant XHTML strict.

Answer (score 0):

In IE, to get inline-block behavior, you set it to display: inline and give it 'hasLayout' via one of the methods (zoom: 1 is a common way).

Answer (score 0):

Use a `<span>` inside your `<p>`. It's inline to begin with.

You can't put block elements inside a `<p>`. That's invalid code!

That should solve it.